# Animals in the End?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In the Overworld, I had some llamas on leads and leading them to go in the end portal.

I made them go in before me and then I hopped in and saw them there then I picked up the dropped leads that went through the portal as well and lead the llamas (and some other animals that I had teleported to the end as well) to the portal where the dragon used to be and I lead the animals and made them go through the portal first.

When all the animals had been pushed/lead into the portal I hopped in and read a bit of the thing after but I skipped it. When I was back at a bed in a villager house (I accidentally set my spawn there much earlier and forgot to change it back) I then walked back to my house and the end portal to see the animals have not returned like I did. The animals were not even at the place I had spawned after the end.

Are animals not supposed to go through the talking thing after the portal in the End because of that the animals died or despawned?

The animals went to the End just fine but when I went back after pushing/leading the animals through the portal at the End they were nowhere to be found. If it helps I had made the end portal by myself in creative and went in survival mode (peaceful).

I am playing on the Nintendo Switch.

Comment: They should arrive at world spawn. Of course they don't arrive where you spawn, because if there are multiple players, the game would have no way to know which player's spawn to choose, so it chooses the original world spawn point instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *default* location that anything that enters the Portal from the End is [World Spawn](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#World_spawn).

If you set your spawn elsewhere, then *you* will spawn there. However, since other mobs *cannot* set their own spawn locations, *they* will end up in the Spawn Chunks. The good thing about this is that the Spawn Chunks never unload, so the Mobs there will not de-spawn.